# How To Pass Env Vars to Sass Plugin in Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, gatsby

How do I pass environment variables to the gatsby-sass-plugin? I'd like to be able to pass an environment variable into the loader that I can then use in my scss files. This is not well documented and I'm not sure how to do it.

Reference: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sass/

This does not work:

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-plugin-sass",
  options: {
    additionalData: `$storeName: ${process.env.SHOPIFY_STORE_NAME};`
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this recent GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/27754), those options are not directly valid as it:

> Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an
> options object that does not match the API schema.

This is causing the `options` object to be undefined.

Try upgrading your `gatsby-plugin-sass` to:

```
gatsby-plugin-sass@3.0.0-next.2
```

Check your `node-sass` version too.

Comment: Huge help! Thank you. Got it working now.

Comment: I'm glad to help. If the issue has been solved please consider accepting/upvote the answer to close the issue.